# Failing to remove page title

Tags: magento2.3, page-layouts

I'm trying to remove page title added from `Magento\Downloadable\Controller\Customer\Products::Execute`

```
public function execute()
    {
        $this->_view->loadLayout();
        if ($block = $this->_view->getLayout()->getBlock('downloadable_customer_products_list')) {
            $block->setRefererUrl($this->_redirect->getRefererUrl());
        }
        $this->_view->getPage()->getConfig()->getTitle()->set(__('My Downloadable Products'));
        $this->_view->renderLayout();
    }
```

I've tried to add below piece of code into `catalog_product_view_type_downlodable.xml` but nothing seems to be working.

```
<referenceBlock name="page.main.title" remove="true" />
```

Any ideas ?!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

put that code in downloadable_customer_products.xml and it will work, please find attached screenshot i have tested in my local.[image: frontend]

[image: code]